# How to project additional fields in Go mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

My Go code is:

```
  query := []bson.M{
        bson.M{
      "$match": bson.M{
        "static.created": bson.M{
          "$gt": someDate,
        },
      },
    },
    bson.M{
      "$group": bson.M{
        "_id": "$static.name",
        "count": bson.M{ "$sum": 1 },
      },
    },
    bson.M{
      "$match": bson.M{
        "count": bson.M{
          "$gte":2,
        },
      },
    },
        bson.M{
      "$project": bson.M{
        "count": 1,
        "static.name": 1,
      },
    },
  }


    pipe := c.Pipe(query)
    response := []bson.M{}
    err = pipe.All(&response)
```

In response I should get 3 fields:
_id
count
static.name

But I get only two of them:
_id
count

How could I get additional fields in my response? I have added the field in $project but it doesn't appear in response.

I tried to remote _id field with:

```
bson.M{
  "$project": bson.M{
    "_id": 0,
    "count": 1,
    "static.name": 1,
  },
},
```

and it worked. So the $project works to remove fields but it doesn't work to add them.

Comment: Have you tried your query in the Mongo shell?

Comment: are you using dot notation because `static.whatever` is a an array of objects??  If so, try to `$unwind` the array before the `$project` step. or... If the array is a single object wrapped in an array.. then in the `$group` step you can do something like `{"name": {"$first":"static.name"}}` after you `$unwind` after the `$match` step.

Comment: This is likely because of your `$group` stage by `static.name` and counting. You're no longer carrying over any other fields. If you would like specific answer please provide sample documents